# Can I record a particular tab using JavaScript without showing the whole screen share dialog box?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, rpscreenrecorder

Here, I am using Chrome extension manifest version 3, and I want to add some features and functionality, such as screen recording without showing the screen share dialog box. Of course, I want to give permission for a particular tab without showing the whole dialog box.

I tried
`getDisplayMedia`
but it is showing the whole popup, and I want to record a particular tab, so it did not work. Then, I used
`tabCapture`
but it is not working in both content and background scripts

Comment: `chrome.tabCapture` can do it in ManifestV2, but it's broken in MV3, see https://crbug.com/1214847. Try opening a new window via chrome.windows.create with an html page of your extension that shows a button to start capturing, and in the click listener you would then minimize this window via chrome.windows.update and use chrome.tabCapture.